# Using Incrond Inotify but having issues with user groups/permissions

Tags: linux, ubuntu, nginx, terminal, inotify

In the /etc/incron.allow I added both:

```
root
USER_1
```

Then I edited the incrontab so it looks like this:

```
/var/www/laravel/public/js/main.js IN_MODIFY yui-compressor -o /var/www/laravel/public/js/main.min.js /var/www/laravel/public/js/main.js
```

I think the issue may have something to do with permissions or perhaps groups but I'm not sure as I'm not getting anything when I check with `tail -f /var/log/syslog`

The `/var/www/laravel/public` folder is owned by `USER_1` in group `www-data`. Incrond Inotify is done by the `root` user. When the main.js file is updated shouldn't Incrond Inotify run regardless of the current user since it's been set by `root`? Why isn't it working and how can I make it work with either `root` or `USER_1`?

Comment: http://unix.stackexchange.com/q/219548/13792

Answer (score 0, accepted):

The problem was due to permissions. It required the read and execute access of all parent and child directories to the file. It seems yui-compressor (Java) has to traverse the directories to get to the file. If it can't get to the directory, then it fails.